# how can i fix zsh: unrecognized modifier `P'

Tags: zsh

While doing as follow on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
pek-ygao-d1% bad_pwd="/${(l:16000:: :):-}"
pek-ygao-d1% print ${bad_pwd:P}
zsh: unrecognized modifier `P'
And the version is zsh 5.4.2-dev-0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu).
```

Please tell me how can I make this work?

Comment: While this might, indeed, be a bug in `zsh`, why exactly do you need to make this work? What path do you have that needs 16,000 spaces?

Comment: thanks for your reply, It's a test in zsh source code, I had backported a patch for fixing a CVE. The ':P' is not added in my zsh version.